# SQL Join for Five Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I am actually trying to Join Five Tables in MySQL Database based upon RegionID which is a unique key present in all tables. I am new to it and using the following left join statement:

```
SELECT `tbllistings`.*,
       `tblgallery`.*,
       `tbltowns`.*,
       `tblregions`.*,
       `tblcontent`.*,
       `tbllistings`.*,
       `tblgallery`.*,
       `tbltowns`.*,
       `tblregions`.*,
       `tblcontent`.*
FROM   tbllistings
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblregions`
              ON `tbllistings`.`intregionid` = `tblregions`.`intregionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblcontent`
              ON `tblregions`.`intregionid` = `tblcontent`.`intregionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblgallery`
              ON `tblregions`.`intregionid` = `tblgallery`.`regionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tbltowns`
              ON `tblregions`.`intregionid` = `tbltowns`.`intregionid`
```

The problem that I am facing is each value is showing up more then 20+ times and I am unsure why is this happening. What I actually want is to simply join all fields from all tables based on RegionID.

Any help and suggestions are highly welcomed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This means you need more filter data via give condition of mathing column value....add one by one table and get distinct value .

Comment: Try using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: INNER JOIN may get rid of output rows that have all NULLs because of missing rows, but it won't dedup.  DISTINCT will dedup rows.  Cleaning up the query will get rid of the duplicated _columns_.

Comment: Have tried using Inner Join but the same output is produced. Also, I have used tblListings.intRegionID on every ON but still it is producing the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tbllistings`.`intregionid` in every `ON` clause.

```
SELECT `tbllistings`.*,
       `tblgallery`.*,
       `tbltowns`.*,
       `tblregions`.*,
       `tblcontent`.*,
       `tbllistings`.*,
       `tblgallery`.*,
       `tbltowns`.*,
       `tblregions`.*,
       `tblcontent`.*
FROM tbllistings
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblregions`
              ON `tblregions`.`intregionid` = `tbllistings`.`intregionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblcontent`
              ON `tblcontent`.`intregionid` = `tbllistings`.`intregionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tblgallery`
              ON `tblgallery`.`regionid` = `tbllistings`.`intregionid`
       LEFT JOIN `webspace_db`.`tbltowns`
              ON `tbltowns`.`intregionid` = `tbllistings`.`intregionid`
```

Comment: Rigel have tried but its the same case. I even use Inner Join but no matter I do, I am being returned the same values again and again.